# showToast is not working in iOS device

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, error-messages, ios, helper

Here what i have written code to display 'showToast' message in lightning component  and It's not working in iOS (but yes it working as expected in Android and Web).

```
handleFpAdd: function (component, event) {
    var prodIds = [];        
    prodIds.push(event.getSource().get('v.name'));     
    var act = component.get("c.addProductIds");
    act.setParams({ "workOrderId": component.get("v.recordId"),
                   "productids": prodIds });
    act.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
        if (state == 'SUCCESS') {
            component.find('notify').showToast({
                "variant": "success",
                "title":  "Products Added",
                "message": "You may need to refresh the page before you see them above."
            });                                                                                                                                                                                       
        } else {
            component.find('notify').showToast({
                "variant": "error",
                "title":  "Error",
                "message": "There was an Error. The parts were not added to the order."
            });                                                                                                                                                                                        
        }
    });    
    console.log('Calling controller addProduct (handleAdd)');
    $A.enqueueAction(act);                                
},
```

[image: THIS IS WHAT I AM GETTING WHEN TRYING TO ADD PRODUCT AND SHOWTOAST COMES UP]

Comment: For mobile devices, better UX would be to show inline message as implemented in standard screen. Not sure, if showToast is good practice for such scenario.